# Why Rstudio doesn't open scripts from projects when projects are copied on a new machine

Tags: r, scripting, project, rstudio

I recently moved a lot of my Rstudio projects from a desktop computer to my laptop. Surprisingly when I open the projects on my laptop it doesn't bring back the scripts I have in them. I checked back with the desktop and they are fine and it opens them. Is there any known solution to that? 
The only thing I can say is on my laptop I have 32bit version of R but on desktop is 64. Let me know if any further information can help.

Best,

Comment: I tried copying the folder to another location and I can't  replicate this (Rstudio 0.98.1091). Can you move this project folder around the desktop to see if you can replicate the behavior?

Comment: On the same computer its fine when I move the project folder. The problem occurs when I copy it to another computer. Thanks for looking into that. On the computer that it works (Rstudio 0.98.1074) and on the one that it doesn't open the scripts it is (Rstudio 0.98.1091).